# GitHub pages root leading to a different repository than username.github.io

Tags: github, github-pages

Assuming `awesome-organisation` has a repository called `awesome-repository`, **is there any way `https://awesome-organisation.github.io` will lead to the `awesome-repository`'s content apart from renaming `awesome-repository` to `awesome-organisation.github.io`?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**, there is not.

---

Source: *contacted GitHub support*